# Typeerror expected str instance, float found

Tags: python, pandas, join

This is a 4 GB dataset that looks like this :

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJaC1.png)

The following code is being run to get all records that have stars>4

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter
data = pd.read_csv("yelp_academic_dataset_review.csv")
temp=" ".join(data[data["stars"]>=4]["text"].values)
```

error at the above statement :

```
TypeError                                 
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-76631d7041ba> in <module>()
----> 1 temp=" ".join(data[data["stars"]>=4]["text"].values)

TypeError: sequence item 2320417: expected str instance, float found
```

The code that follows spits and counts words :

```
temp2=temp.split(sep=" ")
c=Counter(temp2)
count=c.most_common()
data2=pd.DataFrame(count,columns=["word","count"])
```

EDIT : earlier with

```
temp=" ".join(data[data["stars"]<=3]["text"].values)
```

I used to get words in the output of count. Now I get something like this after the str() implementation.

```
    [('', 1650),
    ('e', 466),
    ('t', 298),
    ('o', 277),
    ('a', 258),
    ('n', 240),
    ('s', 211),
```

Comment: Can you show us sequence item 2320417?

Comment: Thanks for your comment @aryamccarthy. Sequence item 2320417 is a space/empty character.

Comment: @aryamccarthy ive added more information in the post. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your type is wrong. Join will not convert float type to string automatically. 
Basically, `data[data["stars"]>=4]["text"].values` returns a float value, and you're trying to join it with a string. So, try this way:

```
" ".join(str(data[data["stars"]>=4]["text"].values))
```

Comment: Curious how temp=" ".join(data[data["stars"]<=3]["text"].values) works flawlessly @steven-li

Answer (score 0):

You should look the traceback.
It is saying it is a TypeError.

Your join statement should be used like this `" ".join(str(data[data["stars"]>=4]["text"].values))`

Comment: ive added some more information in the original post @RushalVerma